# Using web workers with Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, web-worker

Premise: A complete Sencha touch/Js noob with a Java background - (5 days)

Is it possible to use HTML5 web workers with Sencha Touch? The scenario I have is, I have an app made with Sencha Touch 2 and packaged with phone gap and in one of the scenarios, on clicking a button a controller makes an API call which renders the UI inactive for a little bit - I would ideally like to move this to a secondary thread and keep the UI as responsive as possible, but since JS is single threaded I want to leverage HTML5 webworkers for Sencha touch . I found **[this](https://market.sencha.com/extensions/ext-ux-webworker)** plugin but can I use this with Sencha Touch 2 ? If not what are the other options I have. Mind you this is for mobile/tablet dev with Sencha touch and not extJS for desktops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've understood from your question is that you want to use webworkers to render UIs, right?
I think it's impossible because the scope of webworkers is very limited. Here's the list of things that webworkers can access:

- *The navigator object*
- *The location object (read-only)*
- *XMLHttpRequest*
- *setTimeout()/clearTimeout() and setInterval()/clearInterval()*
- *The Application Cache*
- *Importing external scripts using the importScripts() method*
- *Spawning other web workers*

And this is the list of things that webworkers can't access:

- *The DOM (it's not thread-safe)*
- *The window object*
- *The document object*
- *The parent object*

Follows a list of webworkers use cases:

- *Prefetching and/or caching data for later use*
- *Code syntax highlighting or other real-time text formatting*
- *Spell checker*
- *Analyzing video or audio data*
- *Background I/O or polling of webservices*
- *Processing large arrays or humungous JSON responses*
- *Image filtering in*
- *Updating many rows of a local web database*

For more informations about webworkers and their enviroment: **http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/**

Talking about my extension: I don't think it goes well for Sencha because it uses Ext structures and classes.

In the end, I don't know any Sencha UX for webworkers.

**UPDATE (2013/03/20)**

[ExtJS-WebWorker](https://github.com/wilk/ExtJS-WebWorker) now works for Sencha Touch too!

Comment: Well what I have is - I have a list that makes an API call so when I click on the button that loads the list the UI thread makes this call and the UI hangs. Is there a way I can load the list items as they come from a background worker thread using web workers.? in sencha touch. I am also assuming extJs and Sencha touch go hand in hand and I can use these web worker classes

Comment: @Wilk. Does your web-worker runs in a separate thread? I am using webworker0 from the demos and calling its compute using webworker0.send('compute') and downloading in the compute() function. But the ui still hangs?  http://pastebin.com/xtVdfRKR